# Postgresql index stops being used after time, gets picked back up after re-creating

Tags: postgresql, index

I'm confused as to what exactly is going on here. Hoping someone can provide some insight. Why did the index stop being used after time? Why does re-creating it work? Would there be a better index?

At the start I want to already say: thanks to anyone who takes a look or leaves a suggestion.

Here follows all data I could think to gather:

- Postgresql 11.2
- Table with 30 million rows, 20GB in size

Conf setting:

```
shared_buffers = 1024MB
effective_cache_size = 2048MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.5
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 32MB # should probably not raise

# Cannot be raised
max_worker_processes = 4
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2
max_parallel_workers = 4
```

Using this query to get some statistics:

```
SELECT
    pt.tablename AS TableName
    ,t.indexname AS IndexName
    ,to_char(pc.reltuples, '999,999,999,999') AS TotalRows
    ,pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(quote_ident(pt.tablename)::text)) AS TableSize
    ,pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(quote_ident(t.indexrelname)::text)) AS IndexSize
    ,to_char(t.idx_scan, '999,999,999,999') AS TotalNumberOfScan
    ,to_char(t.idx_tup_read, '999,999,999,999') AS TotalTupleRead
    ,to_char(t.idx_tup_fetch, '999,999,999,999') AS TotalTupleFetched
FROM pg_tables AS pt
LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_class AS pc 
    ON pt.tablename=pc.relname
LEFT OUTER JOIN
( 
    SELECT 
        pc.relname AS TableName
        ,pc2.relname AS IndexName
        ,psai.idx_scan
        ,psai.idx_tup_read
        ,psai.idx_tup_fetch
        ,psai.indexrelname 
    FROM pg_index AS pi
    JOIN pg_class AS pc 
        ON pc.oid = pi.indrelid
    JOIN pg_class AS pc2 
        ON pc2.oid = pi.indexrelid
    JOIN pg_stat_all_indexes AS psai 
        ON pi.indexrelid = psai.indexrelid 
)AS T
    ON pt.tablename = T.TableName
WHERE pt.schemaname='public'
ORDER BY 1;
```

The result:

```
                  tablename                   |                         indexname                          |    totalrows     | tablesize  | indexsize  | totalnumberofscan |  totaltupleread  | totaltuplefetched 
----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+------------+------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------
 mytable                                      | myindex                                                    |       30,000,000 | 20 GB      | 48 MB      |           111,166 |    3,294,259,230 |       13,524,499
```

The index:

```
"myindex" btree (zulu_india, mike_romeo) WHERE a_and_not_b(four_lima, bravo_romeo)
```

The function is this:

```
create or replace function a_and_not_b(four_lima bool, bravo_romeo bool)
returns BOOLEAN as $$
   select $1 AND NOT $2;
$$
language sql immutable;
```

The query:

```
select
    distinct quebec,
    zulu_india,
    mike_romeo,
    bravo_romeo,
    four_lima
from
    mytable
where
    bravo_romeo = false
    and four_lima = true
    and zulu_india <= '2021-03-12 00:00:00.005'
order by
    mike_romeo asc,
    quebec asc
limit 100 offset 1300;
```

`quebec` is an id(bigint)

`zulu_india` is a timestamp without timezone

`mike_romeo` is a text

`bravo_romeo` is a boolean

`four_lima` is a boolean

And the index does not get used. A sequential scan gets used.

After recreating, the stats look like this:

```
                  tablename                   |                         indexname                          |    totalrows     | tablesize  | indexsize  | totalnumberofscan |  totaltupleread  | totaltuplefetched 
----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+------------+------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------
 mytable                                      | myindex                                                    |       30,000,000 | 20 GB      | 688 kB     |                 0 |                0 |           0
```

Smaller, but the initial one was small too.

Statistics for the query without the index:

```
Limit  (cost=17091631.17..17091646.17 rows=100 width=3254) (actual time=202217.922..202218.138 rows=100 loops=1)
    Buffers: shared hit=1148 read=2763740
  ->  Unique  (cost=17091436.17..18273890.07 rows=7883026 width=3254) (actual time=202215.055..202217.967 rows=1400 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=1148 read=2763740
        ->  Sort  (cost=17091436.17..17111143.73 rows=7883026 width=3254) (actual time=202215.049..202215.370 rows=1400 loops=1)
                Sort Key: mike_romeo, quebec, zulu_india, four_lima, bravo_romeo
                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3798kB
                Buffers: shared hit=1148 read=2763740
              ->  Seq Scan on oscar_tango mike_three  (cost=0.00..3247634.00 rows=7883026 width=3254) (actual time=2076.567..202130.550 rows=4958 loops=1)
                      Filter: ((NOT bravo_romeo) AND four_lima AND (zulu_india <= 'four_november'::timestamp without time zone))
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 38603368
                      Buffers: shared hit=1148 read=2763740
Planning time: 6.364 ms
Execution time: 202218.535 ms
```

Statistics for the query with the index:

```
Limit  (cost=17180505.79..17180520.79 rows=100 width=3253) (actual time=143.841..143.964 rows=100 loops=1)
    Buffers: shared read=3290
  ->  Unique  (cost=17180310.79..18373240.69 rows=7952866 width=3253) (actual time=141.242..143.804 rows=1400 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared read=3290
        ->  Sort  (cost=17180310.79..17200192.96 rows=7952866 width=3253) (actual time=141.238..141.530 rows=1400 loops=1)
                Sort Key: mike_romeo, quebec, zulu_india, four_lima, bravo_romeo
                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3798kB
                Buffers: shared read=3290
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on oscar_tango mike_three  (cost=2092.88..3213354.03 rows=7952866 width=3253) (actual time=8.761..73.799 rows=4958 loops=1)
                      Recheck Cond: ((zulu_india <= 'four_november'::timestamp without time zone) AND four_lima AND (NOT bravo_romeo))
                      Heap Blocks: exact=3207
                      Buffers: shared read=3290
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on alpha  (cost=0.00..104.66 rows=7952866 width=0) (actual time=8.005..8.005 rows=4958 loops=1)
                            Index Cond: (zulu_india <= 'four_november'::timestamp without time zone)
                            Buffers: shared read=83
Planning time: 96.897 ms
Execution time: 147.054 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cost estimates of the two plans are almost identical, so small differences in the size of the index could be enough to change which one is believed to be faster.

If your row estimates were remotely accurate, the two plans wouldn't be so close to tied, and so wouldn't be subject to changing position based on small changes in index packing density.

<s>There are some unavoidable reasons that estimates can be way off, but in your case even the very simple "Bitmap Index Scan on alpha" with a single hard-coded comparator values is way off, and that is hard to explain by anything other than your table statistics are extremely out of date. You should run `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the table (or on the whole database), as well as investigate how they got so out of date to begin with.</s>

Now I see what is going on. I was ignoring the partial index definition you showed us, because the name of the defined index didn't match the name of the index in the plan, and because the WHERE clause in the index didn't match the WHERE clause of the query.  But that was dumb of me.  The names don't match because the plan was anonymized, and PostgreSQL is smart enough to match up the WHERE clauses because it in-lines the function definition somewhere along the line.  So this is a case where the poor estimates are largely unavoidable without taking special steps.  Almost all the selectivity of the index comes from its where clause, not from the timestamp cutoff. But this WHERE clause selectivity is poorly estimated.  The two booleans must have an interdependence which makes the combination used here much more selective than you would get by multiplying their two selectivities (which is what PostgreSQL does).  PostgreSQL "knows" that the partial index is very small, but doesn't use that knowledge in estimating the joint selectivity.

If this analysis is correct, you can probably fix the problem by creating a multicolumn statistics:

```
create statistics br_fl_stats on bravo_romeo, four_lima from mytable;
analyze mytable;
```

However, I suspect that you would need to upgrade to v12 for this to work, as I think you need multicolumn MCV statistics, which weren't added until then.

Comment: There's a cronjob that runs `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the database daily. Has been for over a year now. And I do see it come up every day in the logs and I'm also seeing the daily drop in dead rows. So it's definitely running. Also, I tried `amcheck` and the index turns up fine. Does `VACUUM ANALYZE` fully update table/index statistics? I'm gonna go check the postgres documentation on what exactly is says about that and about table statistics.

Comment: Does your table turn over almost entirely within a day?  That seems likely given how few tuples there that were more than a day old.  If so, once a day is too little for ANALYZE.  Did you do something to disable/discourage autoanalyze?

Comment: No special settings have been created for this table. That being said, I'm reading that the default for auto-analyze is 50 tuples changed: https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/autovacuum_analyze_threshold/11/ and also, during my tests I did a manual `VACUUM ANALYZE` of the entire database before I started testing and it still resulted in the results I put up here. Including the fact that dropping and re-creating the index means it gets used again.

Comment: I'm not sure what "turn over" means, English isn't my first language. Also, I'm reading the documentation here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-analyze.html and this line seems important: "For large tables, ANALYZE takes a random sample of the table contents, rather than examining every row... To avoid this, raise the amount of statistics collected by ANALYZE, as described below." The table **is** rather large, I think? Could it be that the index isn't being used because it only looks at a small amount of the table, not including the items that fit in the index?

Comment: 'Turn over' meaning that almost all the rows that are present get deleted and replaced with different ones over the course of one day (or updated so they have a different value in zulu_india).  I wouldn't expect the statistics target to be a problem for this estimation (or at least, would not explain a difference between 7952866 and 4958)

Comment: No, deletes rarely happen, mostly inserts and updates. I'm seeing about 37K inserts per week and about 900K updates per week. So that's about 134K changes per day, which is about 0.44% of the table. About the statistics target, I am worried about the documentation saying it takes a "random sample of table contents" if there's the table is "large". What if that sample does not contain any of the values that this index exists for?

Comment: Hello again. Didn't have the time for this in the past weeks. Reading your updated statement basically confirms what I've feared. I've been testing with higher statistics on the involved columns, but to no avail.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, as I fear there not much to do besides upgrade or recreate the index every time it stops being picked up, for the moment. Which is highly inefficient, but what can you do...

Comment: Finally, for the moment, increasing work_mem from 32MB to 64MB seems to make the index be picked up again... Not sure if I can justify that amount on the server running the db though. Multiply by amount of connections, and then also by possible sub-query per query. Hmmmm...